# String replace in SAS?

Tags: sas

Let's say I have a file A1.txt and a file A2.txt. I have written the statements

```
filename in1 'A1.txt';
filename in2 'A2.txt';
```

Now, I want to re-do this using B1 and B2 (and eventually C1, C2, D1, D2), and just rename the variable in one place. So, I want a statement like

```
%let prefix = 'B';
```

and then I want to put that prefix in the filename statements.

```
filename in1 '&prefix1.txt';
filename in2 '&prefix2.txt';
```

I'm not doing this in a data statement. I can almost get it. filename in1 &prefix'.txt' tries to read B'.txt but that extra quote is pesky. There's something vague in my memory banks about using an _ but I can't pull it out.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of questions can I ask here?

    * statistical and data-driven computing (e.g., questions about R, SAS, SPSS, Stata and Minitab)

Comment: see the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Questions about statistical packages are usually on tricky ground, since sometimes they do not have any statistical content, but community usually answers them out of good spirits.

Comment: @mpiktas That's correct, but SAS seems special IMHO, because it is *solely* for statistics (and, AFAIK, it is not ever used by non-statisticians: who could afford to?).  Where else on SE would one reasonably pose such a question and expect an answer?

Comment: @whuber, note that original comment asked about all statistical packages. I agree that SAS is different, that is why I usually upvote all the questions about it. What I wanted to say in the comment, that our community is nice, so even if question is not strictly on topic, it usually gets answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a period:  `&prefix.1.txt`, where the period after `&prefix` tells SAS that the name of the macro variable is finished. If you don't have the "1", then you need two periods: `&prefix..txt`.

Comment: Yes, a colleague came by and I got him to help. It was also an issue putting the name in quotes in the assignment statement.